# How to add a item on title bar in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a navigation bar, and I want to custom it. Here is I want:
[navigationBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYFkJ.jpg)
I tried the navigationBarItems, but it’s not working.

Comment: can you share your code?

Answer (score 1):

Adjust to you're needs:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Test")
            }

            .navigationBarTitle("Summary")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: { }, label: {
                Image("Your image name")
            })
            )

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: He wants to add a button to the **title bar**, which is the top part of windows in macOS. `navigationBarItems` isn't available in macOS.

Answer (score 1):

I have attached the code for your needs. Kindly adjust the image according to your need.

```
\\call this function in viewdidLoad() 
func addNavBarImage() {
        
        let navController = navigationController!
        
        let image = UIImage(named: "Image.png") //Your logo url here
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        
        let bannerWidth = navController.navigationBar.frame.size.width
        let bannerHeight = navController.navigationBar.frame.size.height
        
        let bannerX = bannerWidth / 2.5 - (image?.size.width)! / 2.5
        let bannerY = bannerHeight / 2 - (image?.size.height)! / 2
        
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: bannerX, y: bannerY, width: bannerWidth, height: bannerHeight)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        
        navigationItem.titleView = imageView
}
```